# How to make a QTextDocument as a widget?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtextdocument, qframe, qvboxlayout

I need to build a widget, which bases on `QTextDocument`.

**MyWidget.h**

```
class MyWidget: public QFrame
{
public:
   explicit MyWidget( QWidget *p_parent );

private:
   QTextDocument m_textDocument;
};
```

**MyWidget.cpp**

```
MyWidget::MyWidget( QWidget *p_parent ) : QFrame( p_parent )
{
  QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout( this );
  layout->setMargin( 0 );
  layout->setSpacing( 0 );

  m_textDocument = new QTextDocument( this );
  layout->addWidget( m_textDocument );   // does not work
  layout->addLayout(m_textDocument->documentLayout());  // I have tried this, but incompatible
}
```

I can not `addWidget` because `QTextDocument` is an object. How can I do to build my widget?

Answer (score 4):

You don't use a QTextDocument as a widget, because a Document is the `idea` in memory of what a document is, it does not have a Graphicsl Representation.

If you are looking for a Visual representation of a Document, you can use QTextEdit as follows:

```
auto *textEdit = new QTextEdit(parent);
textEdit->setDocument(myTextDocument);
layout->addWidget(textEdit);
```